# Not able to drop hive table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I upgraded my CDH from 5.0.0 beta to 5.2.1 using Cloudera Manager. All services are running properly except hive metastore. I'm using [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) for the hive metastore.

I'm not able to drop a table from hive when I fire a query like:

```
`drop table test;`
```

I get following error.

```
hive> drop table test;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDOException: Exception thrown when executing query
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:596)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.deleteTableColumnStatistics(ObjectStore.java:6030)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.dropTable(ObjectStore.java:813)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:108)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.dropTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.drop_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1525)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.drop_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8072)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$drop_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8056)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:107)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:502)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:118)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column       AO.BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE in field list
```

**Reference link**

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/CDH-upgrade-from-4-7-to-CDH-5-2-hive-metastore-issue/td-p/20626

Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I tried to do what was suggested in the reference link, but I still had the same problem (even when I fixed all the errors I could see when running the scripts).

Finally, I looked for that BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE in the Hive metastore scripts, and I saw it in every hive-schema-0.1*.0.mysql.sql in the following create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAB_COL_STATS` (
 `CS_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `DB_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `TABLE_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `COLUMN_TYPE` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `TBL_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `LONG_LOW_VALUE` bigint(20),
 `LONG_HIGH_VALUE` bigint(20),
 `DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE` double(53,4),
 `DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE` double(53,4),
 `BIG_DECIMAL_LOW_VALUE` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin,
 `BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin,
 `NUM_NULLS` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `NUM_DISTINCTS` bigint(20),
 `AVG_COL_LEN` double(53,4),
 `MAX_COL_LEN` bigint(20),
 `NUM_TRUES` bigint(20),
 `NUM_FALSES` bigint(20),
 `LAST_ANALYZED` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CS_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `TAB_COL_STATS_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`TBL_ID`) REFERENCES `TBLS` (`TBL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PART_COL_STATS` (
 `CS_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `DB_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `TABLE_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `PARTITION_NAME` varchar(767) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `COLUMN_NAME` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `COLUMN_TYPE` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
 `PART_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `LONG_LOW_VALUE` bigint(20),
 `LONG_HIGH_VALUE` bigint(20),
 `DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE` double(53,4),
 `DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE` double(53,4),
 `BIG_DECIMAL_LOW_VALUE` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin,
 `BIG_DECIMAL_HIGH_VALUE` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin,
 `NUM_NULLS` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `NUM_DISTINCTS` bigint(20),
 `AVG_COL_LEN` double(53,4),
 `MAX_COL_LEN` bigint(20),
 `NUM_TRUES` bigint(20),
 `NUM_FALSES` bigint(20),
 `LAST_ANALYZED` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CS_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `PART_COL_STATS_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`PART_ID`) REFERENCES `PARTITIONS` (`PART_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I checked in the Hive metastore database for those tables I got something different:

```
mysql> desc TAB_COL_STATS;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CS_ID             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AVG_COL_LEN       | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_NAME       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_TYPE       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DB_NAME           | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LAST_ANALYZED     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_HIGH_VALUE   | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_LOW_VALUE    | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MAX_COL_LEN       | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_DISTINCTS     | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_FALSES        | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_NULLS         | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_TRUES         | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| TBL_ID            | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TABLE_NAME        | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc PART_COL_STATS;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CS_ID             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AVG_COL_LEN       | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_NAME       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| COLUMN_TYPE       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DB_NAME           | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_HIGH_VALUE | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DOUBLE_LOW_VALUE  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LAST_ANALYZED     | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_HIGH_VALUE   | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LONG_LOW_VALUE    | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MAX_COL_LEN       | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_DISTINCTS     | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_FALSES        | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_NULLS         | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| NUM_TRUES         | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PART_ID           | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| PARTITION_NAME    | varchar(767) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| TABLE_NAME        | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So since both tables were empty I just dropped and created them again, with the create statements listed in the hive-schema-0.13.0.mysql.sql file.

After doing so I could drop the Hive tables again.